# html submit comment to document

Tags: python, html, forms, file

I am trying to add a comment form to my HTML test site, but i can not get the form to write the comments to a file.

```
<form action="/Users/kyle/server/comments.html" method="POST">
    Your name: <br>
    <input type="text" name="realname"><br>
    <br>Your email: <br>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <br>Your comments: <br>
    <textarea name="comments" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can i get the form to write comments to the file?

This is the python code that i am using for the server

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer

PORT_NUMBER = 8080

#This class will handles any incoming request from
#the browser
a = open("/Users/kyle/server/web-test.html")
site=a.read()
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    #Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        # Send the html message
        self.wfile.write(site)
        return

try:
    #Create a web server and define the handler to manage the
    #incoming request
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    print 'Started httpserver on port ' , PORT_NUMBER

    #Wait forever for incoming htto requests
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '^C received, shutting down the web server'
    server.socket.close()
```

Comment: You need some sort of backend programming language such as php, java, or python to do this. HTML alone is a markup language and is not able to do this.

Comment: I made a server using python and it hosts the website for assess on my home network.

Comment: Are you talking about `<!-- this kind of comments -->`?

Comment: I am talking about the feedback comments, like the one that i am making now.

Comment: See first comment then, again.

Comment: See [the HTML forms specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implementing-the-server-side-processing-for-a-form)

Comment: @kylek if you use [**XAMPP**](http://sawmac.com/xampp/) to make yourself a home server on your PC then you can use `PHP` and `HTML` to receive data from your form and even `MySQL` to store it on a database.

Comment: What are the benefits over a server written in python.

Comment: Your server have to run scripts and than you use `<form action="/Users/kyle/server/script_writing_to_file_and_showing_comments_again.py" method="POST">`

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "made a server using Python"? Do you mean you're using a web server written in Python, or do you mean have a Python web application? If you mean a web server that happens to be written in Python, which one?

Comment: It is a server written in Python 3, on mac 10.8

Comment: What's the name of it? Or is it something you wrote yourself? Any information on what technologies you're using would be helpful in coming up with a more specific solution.

Comment: I posted the python code that i am using for the server.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about non-programming issues with html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code, you will need to extend `myHandler` to handle a POST request, and then in the method that accepts a POST request, you will need to parse the form data out yourself. This site provides a simple example of getting POST data: http://pymotw.com/2/BaseHTTPServer/#http-post. Once you have the comment from the form data, you can write it to a file like you normally would in any other Python application. Here is some Python documentation on reading and writing files if you need it: http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files.

That said, code like this that operates directly on raw requests is not usually written for production use. Generally speaking, web applications are developed using a framework that has pieces that do a lot of this work for you. The framework is often run under an independent web server. For example, [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is a web application framework, and you might run your Django application using [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) and [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/).

In terms of other frameworks, I'm fond of [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) personally. You might find [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) interesting since CherryPy provides both a web application framework and a web server to run it under, which might be better to minimize server set up issues while you're just beginning to learn about web applications. (flask does come with a development server you could use just for testing, but that development server is hardly ready for production use.)

Comment: @kylek Glad to be of service. Mind if I ask what you ended up using?